# Kafka sink connector --> postgres, fails with avro JSON data

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I setup a Kafka JDBC sink to send events to a PostgreSQL.
I wrote this simple producer that sends JSON with schema (avro) data to a topic as follows:

**producer.py (kafka-python)**

```
biometrics = {
        "heartbeat": self.pulse, # integer
        "oxygen": self.oxygen,# integer
        "temprature": self.temprature, # float
        "time": time # string
    }

avro_value = {
               "schema": open(BASE_DIR+"/biometrics.avsc").read(),
               "payload": biometrics
             }

producer.send("biometrics",
                      key="some_string",
                      value=avro_value
                      )
```

**Value Schema:**

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "biometrics",
    "namespace": "athlete",
    "doc": "athletes biometrics"
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "heartbeat",
            "type": "int",
            "default": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "oxygen",
            "type": "int",
            "default": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "temprature",
            "type": "float",
            "default": 0.0
        },
        {
            "name": "time",
            "type": "string"
            "default": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

**Connector config (without hosts, passwords etc)**

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_sink",
    "connector.class": "io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter ",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "topics": "biometrics",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "auto.create": "true"
}
```

But my connector fails hard, with three errors and I am unable to spot the reason for any of them:

**TL;DR; log Version**

```
(Error 1) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: biometrics
(Error 2) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
(Error 3) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

**Full log**

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: biometrics
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

Could someone help me understand those errors and the underlying reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you need to use the JSONConverter class w/ `value.converter.schemas.enabled=true` in your Connector since that was what was produced, but the `schema` payload is **not** an Avro schema represntation of the `payload`, so it might still fail with those changes alone...

If you want to actually send Avro, then use the AvroProducer in `confluent-kafka` library, which requires running the Schema Registry.

Comment: I used `confluent-kafka` instead of `python-kafka`, that supports avro producers out of the box  and it worked flawlessly. Thank you.